# Suggestion: Add https://hsm.stackexchange.com/ as a migration option

Tags: feature-request, migration

Occasionally we get questions that are focused on the history of mathematics, for which there is the lovely https://hsm.stackexchange.com/ .  Can we get that added to the "belongs on another stack exchange" close reasons?

Comment: Related older threads [1](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35270/11619), [2](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32166/11619), [3](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30785/11619), [4](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23531/11619).

Comment: In general, migrations should be rare.  It is typically easy for us (the community, not the moderators) to know what is off-topic here (since we are, hopefully, mathematics content experts), but it is less clear that a question will be on-topic elsewhere.  We typically prefer it if users themselves migrate questions (delete the version here, then repost).  In the rare instances when this is not possible, we (the moderators) like to ping moderators on other sites and get permission to migrate.